# monacaアプリからの写真撮影でExifに位置情報を付ける方法

Tags: ios, monaca, cordova, gps

monacaで開発をしています。

iOS8.1.2くらいまではアプリからカメラの呼び出しで撮影した写真に位置情報(GPS)がついていたのですが、8.1.3から（？）付加されてないようです。

仕様の問題かmonacaの問題かcordovaの問題かコードの問題か分からないのでアドバイスをいただけると助かります。

```
//カメラ設定
    var _opt = {
        quality: 80                                       //画質(最高100)
        , destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI //取得フォーマット(パス)
        , sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA     //取得方法(カメラ)
        , correctOrientation: true                        //写真の向き(撮影方向に合わせる)
        , saveToPhotoAlbum: true                          //保存する
    };

    //カメラ起動
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onPhotoError, _opt);
```

上記コードで保存したJPEGデータには位置情報が付いてないようです。

以上、よろしくお願いします。

追記：
　https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/blob/master/doc/ja/index.md
　上記を参照し
　config.xmlに

```
<preference name="CameraUsesGeolocation" value="true" />
```

を追記したところできました。

Comment: 自己解決した場合、自身で回答として投稿してください。